# Expected value of a censored poisson

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value, censoring

I have the following density (it's a censored model):

$$f(y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda), & \text{if }y^*=0,1 \\
\frac{\lambda^{y^*}e^{-\lambda}}{y^*!}, & \text{if }y^*=2,3....
\end{cases}$$
Can anyone tell me how do I find the expected value of y?
Thank you.

I'm sorry for the confusing information I originally gave. So, $y^*$ and y are different things. 
$y=y^*\text{ for } y^*\geq2$

$y=1\text{ for } y^*=0,1$

Therefore $y\geq1$. So I tried to do the following to get the expectation, I just don't know if it's correct to get the expectation when you have censored data:

$E[y]=\sum_{y=0}^\infty y*p(y)=1*e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda) +\sum_{y^*=2}^\infty y^**\frac{\lambda^{y}e^{-\lambda}}{y^*!}$

$=e^{-\lambda}+\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!}+\sum_{y^*=2}^\infty y^**\frac{\lambda^{y}e^{-\lambda}}{y^*!}=e^{-\lambda}+\sum_{y^*=1}^\infty y^**\frac{\lambda^{y}e^{-\lambda}}{y^*!}$

$=e^{-\lambda}+\sum_{y^*=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{y}e^{-\lambda}}{(y^*-1)!}=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{y^*=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{y-1}}{(y^*-1)!}= e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{j}}{j!}$

$= e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda$

Can someone please tell me if that's correct please?

Comment: Just for clarification, $y$ and $y^*$ are not the same thing?  Also what is the support of $y$? I assume its $(0,1,2,...)$

Comment: @Rusty presumably $y$ is the uncensored variable and $y^*$ is the censored one (values of $y$ below 2 being recorded in $y^*$ as "below 2"). However, presumably the second line of the pdf should have $\lambda^{y^*}$ on the numerator. The expected value of $y$ would just be $\lambda$ ... but (again, presumably) the actual problem is to estimate $y$. Alternatively the problem might be to find $E(y^*)$. OP: please edit your question to clarify the situation. Is this a question for some subject?

Comment: To define the mean of any censored distribution you'd need to assign a value to each group of indistinguishable observations.  In this case you'd need to assign a value to the case when a count of 0 or 1 cannot be distinguished.  If that value is $x$, then then mean would be $\lambda+e^{-\lambda}(x+x\lambda-\lambda)$.  The value of $x$ could be anything you could reasonably justify but values of $0 \leq x \leq 1$ would probably be likely candidates.

Comment: Please do not use different accounts for creating and editing your question. notice that if you have different accounts, you can easily merge them http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: your solution seems correct